# What is the difference between UITabBar and UITabBarController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

What is the difference between UITabBar and UITabBarController? When is it more beneficial to use one over the other?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS UINavigationBar vs UIToolbar vs UITabBar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722795/ios-uinavigationbar-vs-uitoolbar-vs-uitabbar)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A view is an object that knows how to display data to a user and accept user input.  A controller is an object that knows what data to display to a user and what to do with user input.  A UITabBar is a UIView is a view.  It knows how to display a list of tabs to the user, and how to display feedback to the user when the user interacts with the tabs.  A UITabBarController is a UIViewController is a controller.  It knows what tabs to display to the user, and what to do when the user chooses a tab.

If you have written your own controller object, you can hook a UITabBar up to your controller.  If you have not, then a UITabBarController is a convenient base class from which you can derive your controller.